# Determine whether the following series is convergent or divergent, and find its sum if it is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

**PROBLEM**

Is the following complex series convergent, and if so, what is its sum?

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\cos(n\theta)}{3^n}}, \text{   } \theta \in \mathbb{R}$$

**MY ATTEMPT #1**

Let $$a_n = \frac{\cos(n\theta)}{3^n}.$$
By the Ratio Test
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = \left|\frac{\cos((n+1)\theta)}{3^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{3^n}{\cos(n\theta)}\right| = \frac{1}{3}\cdot\left|\frac{\cos((n+1)\theta)}{\cos(n\theta)}\right|.$$
Let $x = (n+1)\theta, y = n\theta$.  Then we have
$$\frac{x}{y} = \frac{n+1}{n} \to 1 \text{ as } n \to \infty$$
$$L = \lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{1}{3}\cdot\left|\frac{\cos((n+1)\theta)}{\cos(n\theta)}\right|} = \frac{1}{3}\cdot\lim_{n \to \infty}{\left|\frac{\frac{\cos(x)}{x}}{\frac{\cos(y)}{y}}\right|}\cdot\lim_{n \to \infty}{\left|\frac{x}{y}\right|} = \frac{1}{3}\cdot{\frac{\lim_{x \to \infty}{\left|\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\right|}}{\lim_{y \to \infty}{\left|\frac{\cos(y)}{y}\right|}}} \to \frac{1}{3}\cdot\frac{0}{0}.$$
Applying L'Hopital's Rule, we get
$$\frac{1}{3}\cdot{\frac{\lim_{x \to \infty}{\left|\frac{\cos(x)}{x}\right|}}{\lim_{y \to \infty}{\left|\frac{\cos(y)}{y}\right|}}} = \frac{1}{3}\cdot{\frac{\lim_{x \to \infty}{\left|\frac{-x\sin(x) - \cos(x)}{x^2}\right|}}{\lim_{y \to \infty}{\left|\frac{-y\sin(y) - \cos(y))}{y^2}\right|}}}$$

But
$$\lim_{z \to \infty}{\left|\frac{-z\sin(z) - \cos(z)}{z^2}\right|} = \lim_{z \to \infty}{\left|\frac{z\sin(z) + \cos(z)}{z^2}\right|} = \left|\lim_{z \to \infty}{\frac{\sin(z)}{z}}\right| + \left|\lim_{z \to \infty}{\frac{\cos(z)}{z^2}}\right| = 0 + 0 = 0.$$

*HENCE THIS IS NOT THE CORRECT APPROACH.*

**MY ATTEMPT #2**

Still by the Ratio Test,
$$\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = \left|\frac{\cos((n+1)\theta)}{3^{n+1}}\cdot\frac{3^n}{\cos(n\theta)}\right| = \frac{1}{3}\cdot\left|\frac{\cos((n+1)\theta)}{\cos(n\theta)}\right|.$$

Applying the trigonometric identity
$$\cos(A+B) = \cos(A)\cos(B) - \sin(A)\sin(B)$$
to $\cos((n+1)\theta)$ does not appear to help either.

**QUESTION**

> Does this mean that the Ratio Test is not an appropriate test of convergence for this series?  If so, what test should I use, and how?

Comment: Use comparison test (aka Majorant). Can you show that $|a_n|\le1/3^n$? You get uniform convergence as a bonus. All this assuming that you really have $\theta\in\Bbb{R}$ in spite of tagging this as complex analysis.

Comment: Yes, @JyrkiLahtonen.  Your inequality follows from $\left|\cos(n\theta)\right| \leq 1$ (since $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$). This then implies that the series is convergent.  My remaining problem is:  How do I compute its sum?

Comment: Changing **complex-analysis** tag to **real-analysis** tag in a bit.

Comment: for the sum consider the real part of the sum of the geometric series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{e^{i \, \theta}}{3}\right)^n$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, @AnuragA.  Posting an answer in a bit.  I hope it is correct!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As hinted in the comments, the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\cos(n\theta)}{3^n}}$$
is convergent (by the Comparison Test) since $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$ implies that
$$\left|a_n\right| \leq \frac{1}{3^n},$$
where $\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n$ is a convergent geometric series.

Now, to compute the sum, we consider the geometric series
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\bigg(\frac{e^{i\theta}}{3}\bigg)^n}$$
which (since $\left|e^{i\theta}/3\right| = 1/3 < 1$) has sum
$$\frac{1}{1 - \frac{e^{i\theta}}{3}} = \frac{3}{3 - e^{i\theta}} = \frac{\bigg(9 - 3\cos\theta\bigg)+i\bigg(3\sin\theta\bigg)}{\sin^2\theta + \bigg(3 - \cos\theta\bigg)^2}.$$

But by De Moivre's Theorem,
$$(e^{i\theta})^n = e^{i(n\theta)} = \cos(n\theta)+i\sin(n\theta).$$
Hence,
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\frac{\cos(n\theta)}{3^n}} = \Re\Bigg(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\bigg(\frac{e^{i\theta}}{3}\bigg)^n}\Bigg) = \frac{9 - 3\cos\theta}{\sin^2\theta + \bigg(3 - \cos\theta\bigg)^2} = \frac{9 - 3\cos\theta}{10 - 6\cos\theta},$$
where $\Re(z)$ denotes the *real part* of $z \in \mathbb{C}$.